# Mocking calls made to S3 in an AWS Lambda function using Jest

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, mocking, jestjs

I'm trying to mock a call for putObject in a local Node.JS AWS Lambda function using Jest but for some reason I keep getting 0 number of calls in my expect.

Here is my main func(index.js):

```
 const S3 = require("aws-sdk/clients/s3");
 const s3 = new S3();

 exports.handler = async (event) => {

   putFunction = async (params, callback) => {
     await s3.putObject(params, callback).promise();
   };

 const params = {
     Bucket: "some value",
     Key: "some key value",
     ContentType: "application/json",
     Body: "some body value",
   };

   const callback = {
     function(err, data) {
       console.log(JSON.stringify(err) + " " + JSON.stringify(data));
     },
   };
   putFunction(params, callback);
 }
```

I've tried adding async to my test function as I thought it was an asynchronous issue but that I still seem to be receiving the same error. Here is my test code(index.test.js):

```
 let myHandler = require("../../src/lambda/index");
 const mockedPutObject = jest.fn();
 jest.mock("aws-sdk/clients/s3", () => {
   return class S3 {
     putObject(params, cb) {
       mockedPutObject(params, cb);
     }
   };
 });

 it("has to mock s3#putObject", () => {
   const params = {
     Bucket: "test1",
     Key: "test2",
     ContentType: "application/json",
     Body: "test3",
   };

   const callback = {
     function(err, data) {
       console.log(JSON.stringify(err) + " " + JSON.stringify(data));
},
};
   const putFunc = myHandler.handler.putFunction;
   putFunc;
   expect(mockedPutObject).toHaveBeenCalledWith(params, callback);
 });
```

Any help would be great.

Comment: The description for tag [tag:lambda] says "DO NOT USE FOR THE AWS SERVICE".

Comment: sorry about that

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a Jest/Node only answer for those that don't wish to pull in any third-party mocking libraries like [aws-sdk-mock](https://www.npmjs.com/package/aws-sdk-mock).

The problem (without seeing the error itself in your answer) is very likely to be related to the `.promise()` in your implementation code.

You have added this in the implementation to tell the SDK to return you a promise for whatever operation was called.

```
await s3.putObject(params, callback).promise();
```

That returned promise will either reject with an error or resolve with the data.

This means in the promise-based approach you can **omit the callback completely**.

```
await s3.putObject(params).promise();
```

(taken from [this AWS blog post](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/support-for-promises-in-the-sdk/))

### Fixing the handler...

You can either:

#### Put that callback logic in subsequent promise chain blocks:

```
.then((data) => {
  // ... do stuff
})
.catch((err) => {
  // ... handle error
}
```

or better still (as it looks like you're already embracing) the
more modern ES6 approach of

#### Awaiting the putObject promise within in a try-catch block:

```
try {
  const data = await s3.putObject(params).promise()
  // ... do things with data on successful response
} catch (err) {
  // ... handle error
}
```

#### Putting those together

Your handler should look something like this:

```
const { S3 } = require("aws-sdk");
const s3 = new S3();

exports.handler = async (event) => {
  const params = {
    Bucket: "some value",
    Key: "some key value",
    ContentType: "application/json",
    Body: "some body value",
  };

  try {
    const data = await s3.putObject(params).promise();

    // ... do stuff with data

    return {
      statusCode: 200,
      body: JSON.stringify(data),
      // ... etc.
    }
  } catch (err) {
    // ... handle error

    return {
      statusCode: 400, // or any 4XX, 5XX 
      body: '...',     // whatever you wish to return on error
      // ... etc.
    }
  }
}
```

### Fixing the tests...

Bearing in mind that you can omit the callback, the test code needs to reflect the extra `.promise()` in the call chain of the `putObject` in the handler.

In the test file, the SDK mock needs to be configured to:
a) return the top-level `S3` constructor
b) have this `S3` constructor itself return an object containing the `putObject` function
c) have this `putObject` itself return an object containing the `promise` function

So that it can be invoked as the real SDK would:

```
const { S3 } = require("aws-sdk"); // require("aws-sdk") returns { S3 }

const s3 = new S3()                //                    returns { putObject }

await s3.putObject(params)         //                    returns { promise }
        .promise();                //                    returns ...your_mock_response
```

```
// You need to return the { promise } here even if you don't care about
// mock calls beyond the putObject, because the handler itself calls .promise()
// and will throw "TypeError: Cannot read property 'promise' of undefined"

const putObjectMock = jest.fn(() => ({
  promise: jest.fn()
}));

jest.mock('aws-sdk', () => ({
  S3: jest.fn(() => ({
    putObject: putObjectMock,
  })),
}));

// S3 must have jest.fn(...) over an ordinary function otherwise
// the new S3() in the handler will fail.
// Jest does its magic with the function you provide to make it callable as a constructor

const myHandler = require("../../src/lambda/index");

// Don't forget to add the "async" before the "it" callback as your handler is async
it("has to mock s3#putObject", async () => {
  const params = {
    Bucket: "test1",
    Key: "test2",
    ContentType: "application/json",
    Body: "test3",
  };

  await handler(); // Call the handler to then assert against the mock params

  expect(putObjectMock).toHaveBeenCalledWith(params);
});
```

Final note - add your handler import *after* the mock setup to prevent a `"Cannot access 'putObject' before initialization"` error (caused by the handler's require of the SDK).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you I get it now

Comment: Actually I still get a Cannot read property promise of undefined error even after adding returning to promise for pitObjectMock @jamespeiris

Comment: and also get a s3.putObject is not a function

Comment: No problem @RichardDesouza!

Hmm, so I did test the code above before posting it just to make sure it worked and that it would be a copy-paste job.

It's unfortunately quite hard to debug without seeing the code and stack traces themselves - has anything significantly changed in your version?

E.g. requiring `aws-sdk/clients/s3` rather than just `aws-sdk` / the structure of the jest mock has changed

Comment: Actually i was able to fix it. Turns out it was because I wasn't passing params in the jest.mock. Thanks again for the detailed response

Comment: Hey @jamesperiris was wondering if you could check out my new question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61719699/mocking-two-s3-api-calls-in-the-same-aws-lambda-function-using-jest

Comment: Hey again @jamespeiris I'm trying to implement the above code in typescript but now I'm getting s3.putObject is not a function? I've changed const AWS = require("aws-sdk") to import AWS from "aws-sdk" but other than that everything else related to mocking putObject was kept the same. I've also changed exports.handler to export async function myHandler

Comment: Hi @RichardDesouza - so (without seeing the error in context) this sounds to me like a mock issue.

At runtime, your mock implementation that Jest has replaced the original implementation with is not returning an object in the format expected (i.e. S3 returning `{ putObject }`) .

You mentioned you changed the import to just `aws-sdk`, presumably from `aws-sdk/clients/s3` - but did you also update the `jest.mock()` reference to match this?

It's hard to debug without seeing the code/errors - if it's still an issue please make another question so I can better help with this!